# How to make object attr required when creating one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model `Unit`. How do I prohibit `Unit.new` when I have `Unit.new(someAttr: nil , .........)`? I don't have any constructors, and when I try with `validates : someattr , presence: true` it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

validator will be run when `save`, `create`, `update`, `valid?` methods invoked.
So you could try

```
def some_action
  @unit = Unit.create(some_attr: nil)
  # then you can get @unit.errors here
end
```